# What is the difference between the default flair and clean flair?

Tags: support, flair

There are five flairs you can choose from in the user profile:

[image: Flairs]

The hotdog, dark and combined flairs are all obviously different.

The default and clean flairs seem to be indistinguishable to me.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it really just comes down to background color and border. It's easier to see if you look at the same page on meta, where the page background is white:

[image: zcoop98 Flair page on white background]

"Default" is bordered with light grey, and has a grey-filled interior.
"Clean", however, has no border, and has a pure-white fill instead.

Comment: Maybe I am color blind or something, hard to unsee the difference now

Comment: Not so easy to see the difference in the dark theme actually, it depends on screen contrast I guess.